# Is this full or partial specialization of class template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-specialization

In the following example:

```
template <class T, int n>
class MyContainer{
public:
    T myArray[size];
    int size;
    MyContainer() : size(n){}
};
// full or partial specialization?
template <int n>
class MyContainer <double, n>{
public:
    double myArray[n];
    int size;
    MyContainer() : size(n){}
    double sum();
    double average();
};
```

I just started learning full and partial template specializations and this confuses me a bit. Generally, I would say this is a full template specialization since the parameter T is defined as double and there are no other formal parameters left. But, I'm not sure if parameter **n** makes any difference here?

Comment: yes it does, it isn't a full specialization until all parameters in the template parameter list have been specialized/specified

Comment: If it's a type, it's full specialization; if it's a template, it's partial specialization.

Comment: So, If I remove **int n** then it would be a full template specialization?

Comment: Partial. Hint, full specialisation would look `template <>`, i.e. all the parameters have been specialised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does, it isn't a full specialization until all parameters in the [template parameter list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) have been specialized/specified, e.g.

```
template <>
class MyContainer <double, 4> { // Full specialization
....

template <int n>
class MyContainer <double, n> { // Partial specialization
....

template <class T, int n> // Partial specialization (adds something to the base template parameter list: '*')
class MyContainer<T*,n> {
....
```

it doesn't matter if the template parameter is a type or non-type, if you don't specialize all the parameters in the list you won't have a complete specialization.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a full specialization unless all template parameters have been specialized.

`template <>` introduces full specializations.